# Why does using a data structure defined as a preprocessor directive fail to compile?

Tags: c, generics, linked-list

I am trying to create a linked-list with 'generic' nodes in c.
I am told that this is possible yet get compilation errors.
Here is my code:

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType)\
    typedef struct CellType *ListType;\
    struct CellType {\
        EltType element;\
        ListType next;\
    }\

int isInOrder(struct CELL cell, int bool){
    if(cell.next == NULL){
        return bool;
    } else if (c.element > c.next.element){
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        isInOrder(c, TRUE);
    }
}

int main(void){
    /* Create CELLs */
    DefCell(char, CELL, LIST);
    struct CELL a;
    a.element = 'a';
}
```

This does not compile and returns this error:

> Error: variable has incomplete type 'struct CELL'
>   `int isInOrder(struct CELL c, int bool){`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Compiler is correct, what is `struct CELL`? Did you mean to use `struct CellType`.

Comment: Note your recursive function `isInOrder` is ignoring its own return value. Did you mean `return isInOrder(c, TRUE);` ?

Comment: @WeatherVane: code edit has changed unexpected things. macro definition has screwedup.

Comment: `typedef struct CellType *ListType;` Ugh, avoid these

Comment: @TruthSeeker Oh yes, it was riddled with HTML markup tags - corrected.

Comment: @kiranBiradar : not really. [this](https://onlinegdb.com/HkZbUdtzU) was actual code. Macro expansion has struct definition

Answer (score 2):

Here is your code after the preprocessor expansion:

```
int isInOrder(struct CELL cell, int bool){
    if(cell.next == NULL){
        return bool;
    } else if (c.element > c.next.element){
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        isInOrder(c, TRUE);
    }
}

int main(void){
    /* Create CELLs */
    typedef struct CELL *LIST;
    struct CellType {
        char element;
        LIST next;
    };
    struct CELL a;
    a.element = 'a';
}
```

At the point where `isInOrder` is defined, `struct CELL` has not been defined yet. `struct CELL` must be defined before `isInOrder`.

Answer (score 2):

Definition for `struct CELL;` comes from the expansion of macro `DefCell(char, CELL, LIST);` and compiler must able to deduce the argument type before the function definition/declaration.

Like below,

```
DefCell(char, CELL, LIST);

int isInOrder(struct CELL cell, int bool) {
    if (cell.next == NULL) {
        return bool;
    }
    else if (cell.element > cell.next->element) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    else {
        return isInOrder(cell, TRUE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Many errors

1. typedef in the local scope of main.
2. you do not understand the difference between `.` and `->`
3. you pass parameter `c` but try to use `cell`

```
#define DefCell(EltType, CellType, ListType)\
    typedef struct CellType *ListType;\
        struct CellType {\
        EltType element;\
        ListType next;\
    }\

    DefCell(char, CELL, LIST);


int isInOrder(struct CELL c, int bool){
    if(c.next == NULL){
        return bool;
    } else if (c.element > c.next -> element){
        return 0;
    } else {
        isInOrder(c, 0);
    }
}


int main(void){
    /* Create CELLs */
    struct CELL a;
    a.element = 'a';
}
```

Comment: 4. `return isInOrder(c, TRUE);` otherwise not all control paths return a value. (I see you changed the argument from `TRUE` to `0` too).